# error while inserting into set c++

Tags: c++

/*info is a string*/

```
 while(getline(cin,info)){
          char *a = new char[info.size()+1];
          a[info.size()] = 0;
          memcpy(a,info.c_str(),info.size());
          //cout<<sizeof(a)<<endl;
          set<char *>m;
          m.insert(a,a+8);
}
```

//Error:invalid conversion from char to char*

Comment: What are you expecting `m.insert(a,a+8);` to do? And do you understand what `set <char *>` is? It's hard to explain your mistake without understanding what you expect this code to do.

Comment: Whatever you are trying to do, there's almost certainly a much better way to do it. Perhaps you want `set<string>`?

Comment: StackOverflow users really seem to enjoy DVing a post from an inexperienced user. It's such a nice community.

Comment: @prateek behera clarify whether you want a set of pointers to characters, or a set of characters.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the thing you're missing is that when you `insert` a range, it inserts each item in that range. It doesn't try to insert them as a single item but it inserts each item in the range individually.

```
      set<char *>m;
      m.insert(a,a+8);
```

Okay, so `m` is a `set` of `char*`. You've said that you want to insert everything in the range from `a` to `a+8`. That's a range of characters. So you're trying to insert characters into a set of pointers to characters. That can't work.

Perhaps you just want `m.insert(a);`? Since `m` is a `set` of `char*` and `a` is a `char*`, I can't imagine what you might want to do other than insert it.

Comment: Also, looks like the OP needs the first 9 characters (0-8) of `a` to be added. Just create a new `char *` accordingly, and insert this one into `m`

Comment: @HappyCoder Given that he already dynamically allocated `a`, he probably wants to just put the right stuff in `a` and then insert it. But I have a funny feeling he's expecting the `set` to ensure the `char*`'s inserted into it point to unique strings, which of course it won't do.

Comment: We can only speculate with the present available information. Let's wait for his edit.

Answer (score 0):

```
m.insert(a,a+8);
```

You tried to use a wrong overload of `set::insert()`. It is mostly useful when you want to do something like this:

```
int a[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
std::set<int> m;
m.insert(a[0]);
m.insert(a[1]);
...
m.insert(a[6]);
m.insert(a[7]);
```

This is lengthy and we want to avoid repetitions. Equivalently, you can write

```
int a[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
std::set<int> m;
m.insert(a, a+8);
```

Now let's go back to your code...

```
while(getline(cin,info)){
      char *a = new char[info.size()+1];
      ...
      set<char *>m;
      m.insert(a,a+8);
```

Conversely, you can "expand" it into

```
while(getline(cin,info)){
      char *a = new char[info.size()+1];
      ...
      set<char *>m;
      m.insert(a[0]);
      m.insert(a[1]);
      ...
      m.insert(a[6]);
      m.insert(a[7]);
```

Now you see you ended up in `insert`-ing a `char` object to `std::set<char *>`. This is the reason why you got the error message.

### Proposed fix

You defined `set<char *> m` *inside* the `while` loop.  That means you are dealing with a freshly constructed `m` in each iteration of the `while` loop, which doesn't makes sense.  You need to move the definition of `m` to before `while`.

It is not recommended to use `new char[...]` until you spend 5--6 years in C++.   C++ already prepared `std::string` and/or `std::vector` for you to replace 99% of the use cases of raw `new char[...]`.  So your `set` should be `set<string> m`.

`std::string` has an assignment operator (and a copy constructor) which takes a `std::string` or NUL-terminated `const char *` and does `memcpy()` for you, and you can think `set::insert()` internally invokes it.

`std::string` also supports a substring operation returning a fresh `std::string` such that `string("abcde").substr(3) == "abc"`.

- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr

That means you don't need an intermediate variable `a` at all.

After these corrections, you'll get

```
set<string> m;
while(getline(cin,info)){
      m.insert(info.substr(8));
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir for your answer.Actually i am new to competitive programming and experimenting a bit.Sorry if my question was weird.Can you please help me by suggesting how can i do better in competitive programming using c++

Comment: I guess you'd better focus on learning basic programming first rather than programming competition. Java might be a viable option because it has more safeguards than C++. By the way `string("abcde").substr(3) == "abc"` was wrong :-) `string("abcde").substr(0, 3) == "abc"`